# How does create directory if it doesn't exist in PL/pgsql (postgresql)?

Tags: windows, cmd, mkdir

I defined a trigger in postgresql as follow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    COPY (select 1) TO PROGRAM 'mkdir -m 700 -p mfdata';
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now I use this trigger when a record of table `aircraft` updated:

```
CREATE TRIGGER aircraft_test AFTER UPDATE ON aircraft 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test();
```

This means when a record in `aircraft` table updated, `mfdata` directory created if not exist in postgres data directory. First record update, it create a folder whit `mfdata` name, but in second update record, it error:

[image]

for when doesn't create the folder if it exist, I'm using `-p`, but it error.

**Why does it error? How can I fixe it?**

**Note:**
I want to create sub folder dynamically later.

**DB Log:**

```
2018-01-27 08:24:40 IRST LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
A subdirectory or file -m already exists.

Error occurred while processing: -m.

A subdirectory or file 700 already exists.

Error occurred while processing: 700.

A subdirectory or file -p already exists.

Error occurred while processing: -p.

A subdirectory or file mfdata already exists.

Error occurred while processing: mfdata.

2018-01-27 17:34:49 IRST ERROR:  program "mkdir -m 700 -p mfdata" failed
2018-01-27 17:34:49 IRST DETAIL:  child process exited with exit code 1
2018-01-27 17:34:49 IRST CONTEXT:  SQL statement "COPY (select 1) TO PROGRAM 'mkdir -m 700 -p mfdata'"
    PL/pgSQL function test() line 3 at SQL statement
```

Comment: Is there anything in the error log?

Comment: @melpomene I update the question

Comment: Are you doing this on windows? Windows `mkdir` doesn't support `-m` or `-p` or unix permissions.

Comment: @melpomene YES I'm doing it on win10.  Are you sure does not support in windows? Where is its reference? Is there any solution?

Comment: If you need to execute OS commands from the PostgreSQL code (definitely bad idea BTW), then try this: https://github.com/petere/plsh PS: Not sure about supporting of the `cmd.exe`. PPS: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490930.aspx

Comment: I had the same requirement of creating a directory path in windwos environment  using a postgres .sql script @MortezaMalvandi  can you help me on this..